Problems with notation in TRPO paper
I want to rewrite the following representation of $\eta(\tilde{\pi})$ into my notation.

I am quite sure that my notation is fine but I can not get rid of the infinite sum in the advantage term. This is my calculation:
$$\eta(\tilde{\pi}) = \eta(\pi) + \mathbb{E}_{S_t\sim d^{\tilde{\pi}},A_t\sim \tilde{\pi}(\cdot|S_t)}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t A_\pi(S_t, A_t)\right] =\eta(\pi) +\sum_{s\in S}d^{\tilde{\pi}}(s_t)\sum_{a\in A}\tilde{\pi}(a_t|s_t)\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^t A_\pi(S_t, A_t)\right]$$
Does anyone have an idea how I fix this?
